# dynamic_bit set print?

Tags: c++, boost, bitsets

```
std::string charBuff = "11010";
dbitset = boost::dynamic_bitset<unsigned char> (charBuff);
for (boost::dynamic_bitset<>::size_type i = 0; i < dbitset.size(); ++i) {
      std::cout << dbitset[i];
}
```

It prints from the LSB to MSB. Output: 01011.

What should I do to so that bitset is printed correctly. I can reverse the character buffer which I am aware of :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<unsigned car>
```

Should be:

```
<unsigned char>
```

What is `buffer`? Shouldn't you use `charBuff`?

Use the `operator<<` overload for `dynamic_bitset`s to achieve what you want. Here's a simplified solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::string charBuff("11010");
    boost::dynamic_bitset<> dbitset(charBuff);

    /* print LSB to MSB, in order */ 
    for (boost::dynamic_bitset<>::size_type i = 0; 
         i < dbitset.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << dbitset[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    /* print bits in the order you want */
    std::cout << dbitset << std::endl; 
    return 0;
}
```